# MySQL - Update rows with no id in PDO

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
|--------|-----------|
| SET_Id | SET_Value |
|--------|-----------|
|  Item1 |    Banana |
|  Item2 |     Apple |
|--------|-----------|
```

How can I update these lines if I have only these infos:

```
$Item1 = "Bananas" // New value
$Item2 = "Apples" // New value
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but if I understand correctly you can try this:

```
update table set SET_Value = concat(SET_Value,'s')
--Where condition if applies
```

or if that doesn't work you can create a new table:

```
create table table_v2 as select SET_Id, concat(SET_Value,'s') from table_nm
```

Answer (score 0):

For updates, you can use any columns in the where condition.
So for your table, you can do something like:
`UPDATE table_name SET SET_Value = 'new_value' WHERE SET_Id = 'Item1'`

You can also remove all the where conditions or use multiple columns in the where conditions.